# Backbone does not parsing string inside ();

Tags: c#, jquery, json, backbone.js, soap

I am using Backbone Collection to fetch records. The web services has implement in C# ,Soap.

The Backbone collection syntax are:

```js
define([
   'underscore', 
   'jquery',   
   'backbone'
], function(_, $, Backbone) {

  var GetProductCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

      initialize: function(options){
        console.log("product  initialized");
      },

      url: function(){
        return "http://example.com/WebMethod.aspx?jsonp=&function=GetAllItems";
      },

      //fetch method response 404 before calling parse
      parse: function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }

    });
  return GetProductCollection;
});
```

Once trigger the collection.fetch({success: function(collection, response){}, error: function(collection, response){} }), the desired URL hit to server and brings data's has  shown network tab with 200 status while inspect from browser. Backbone Collection response as 404, and executing error callback function.

The data from exiting web services(APIs) has returned as body content in following format

```js
('[{
  "Status": true,
  "Mesg": [
    {
      "Id": "8f54381a-06f9-4816-84ff-161c594b2cca",
      "Product": {},
    }
},
{
  "Status": true,
  "Mesg": [
    {
      "Id": "8f54381a-06f9-4816-84ff-161c594b2cca",
      "Product": {},
    }
}]');
```

So Backbone does not expecting string inside (); but existing services already integrated with AJAX call of Jquery. So I'm looking to alternative solution that Backbone collection accept response as above format.

Comment: Backbone is expecting JSON and that's not JSON. You might be able to kludge around this using [`Collection#parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) to manually unpack the returned data. I don't know if it will get that far though. Can't you fix the server to send a property response?

Comment: Actually the response has configured for concatenate a callback function name with response.So Its executes automatically on client side.